# Unable to delete partition 2 from device /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91

Tags: vmware-esxi, partition

i have a disk on ESXI, i am trying to delete the partitions that are on it, this is what i did :

```
partedUtil delete /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91 1
partedUtil delete /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91 3 
partedUtil delete /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91 4
```

Everything was working fine, i do the same thing with the coredump partition :

```
 partedUtil delete /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91 9
```

when i go to check the parition list :

```
#partedUtil get /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91
145921 255 63 2344225968
2 7086080 15472639 0 0
```

Now the problem is with this partition, when i try to delete it this is what i am getting :

```
#partedUtil delete /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91 2
Error: Read-only file system during write on /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91
Unable to delete partition 2 from device /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91
```

I spent hours and hours searching for the solution, but i found nothing, any help, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

i have rebooted my server on my esxi iso, once i get this menu :
[image]

i did  alt+F1, enter your login, for the password just hit enter it's blank, run the same command to delete the partition :

```
#partedUtil delete /dev/disks/naa.50000398b8497b91 2
```

and congrats ! it has been deleted successfully :)

run the reboot command, and don't forget to remove your iso image :)